# Как обновить mssql таблицу данными из DataTable через sql-запрос c#

Tags: c#, update, datatable

Есть dbf-таблица. Я выгружаю ее в `DataTable` с помощью `SqlBulkCopy`. Можно ли использовать эту динамическую таблицу в *SQL*-запросе для обновления *SQL*-таблицы?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, Вам стоит покопать в направлении класса [SqlDataAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Этот класс содержит замечательный метод int Update(DataTable dataTable), который позволяет обновить источник данных с помощью DataTable. Цитирую: "Обновляет значения в базе данных, выполняя соответствующие операторы INSERT, UPDATE или DELETE для каждой вставленной, обновленной или удаленной строки в указанном DataTable."

PS надеюсь, что поняла вопрос правильно. :Р

Answer (score 1):

Не нашла информацию, можно ли использовать динамическую таблицу в sql-запросе. Вышла из положения, создав временную таблицу с той же структурой, что и dbf-таблица. В эту таблицу выгрузила данные из динамической таблицы, затем обычный Update.